# How to validate forms on server side, solutions?

Tags: php, html

So how do you validate on the server side the data submited by the form?

you do something like this:

```
if($_POST['field_name'] == 'foo')
{
  $error['field'] = 'Please try again';
}

if($_POST['something'] == 'two')
{
  $error['field_2'] = 'Please try again';
}

if($_POST['field_3'] == 'something')
{
  $error['field_3'] = 'Please try again';
}
```

Is this right? is this the best solution?

//LE EDIT

My question is, if this is the right way to do it? using a lot of if statements, you can have 20 if's to check for a form? I just wanted to make sure that this is the right way to do it, and if I'm using a lot of if statements is not a big deal(problem)

Comment: Are you telling us how to do this, or asking a question ?

Comment: If you have a form with three inputs, one where the use should type `foo`, one where the user should type`two` and one where the user should type `something`, then yes, this is the right way to check if he has done so.

Answer (score 3):

Not really, I don't think you know what the values should be so this will not work.

You should look at every field to determine what it can be. For numbers you can use functions like `is_numeric` and for e-mail addresses and urls you can use php's [filter functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php). For other stuff you can use regular expressions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are already a few libraries (functions, classes) pre-written to handle form validation in PHP.

[http://www.google.com/search?q=form+validation+php](http://www.google.com/search?q=form%20validation%20php)

I doubt that at this point, you need to spend time to write a custom solution for something so generic. Probably your rules would be different, but that's all customizable with existing code.

(Not to mention you could use one of many PHP frameworks, which all have form generation and validation built-in).

Answer (score 0):

Most people use [GREP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) when they write their own validators.  The validations can be stored in functions specific to each type of field.

Most people focus on [SQL Injection validation](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

A good framework, like Code Ignitor, will [provide validation mechanisms](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html).